# handle event android

Tags: android, events

i want to assign the sound for my phone  if a call coming. so how can i catch event if other phone call my phone

Comment: More Information needed..........Why you need such functionality?What you have done until now? Where you get stuck? whats the error?

Comment: i want assign ring if for person so i need to catch the event

Answer (score 0):

As per your limited information i can only suggest you to try [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)

Hope this helps.